# Google Slide image is okey but when downloaded as pdf and opened in Mac's preview software image is gone

Tags: google-slides

I have a Google Slides slide with two images, one on top of the other with the upper image being semi transparent. In Google Slides it looks good, but when I download it as pdf and open it in Mac's default program to see pdfs called 'Preview' the upper image is straight not even loaded. The same pdf opened in any browser looks good, with the upper image as it is supposed.

Link to the example reproducing the issue: [Google Slides | Example](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1l9wdZEpiyGyEsmj31CC4gl68cvCi2WQRiLPJ8V4ZV-s/edit#slide=id.p)

To reproduce just download it as pdf and open it in Mac's preview software

Comment: @KJ It does look good in preview. How did you create that pdf ?